# Exporting tree to excel

Tags: java, tree, export-to-excel

I'm trying to export a tree to an excel sheet and I'm having a problem.

At first I was using a RichTreeTable and I could easy export the data with my export method.

```
 public static void exportDataDrillDownIndiComercial(FacesContext facesContext, OutputStream outputStream, RichTreeTable tree) throws IOException {

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

        CollectionModel treeModel = (CollectionModel) tree.getValue();

        JUCtrlHierBinding treeBinding = (JUCtrlHierBinding) treeModel.getWrappedData();
        List<JUCtrlHierNodeBinding> treeList = treeBinding.getChildren();
```

However, they've changed it to a `ChildPropertyTreeModel`,
and now I have:

```
public static void exportDataDrillDownIndiComercial(FacesContext facesContext, OutputStream outputStream, ChildPropertyTreeModel tree) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8")); 
    CollectionModel treeModel = (CollectionModel) tree;
    JUCtrlHierBinding treeBinding = (JUCtrlHierBinding) tree.getWrappedData(); //getWrappedData on tree or treeModel gives ClassCastException
    List<JUCtrlHierNodeBinding> treeList = treeBinding.getChildren();
```

Whenever I try to `getWrappedData()` I get a ClassCastException, and any other get's I've tryed are not compatible with `JUCtrlHierBinding`.
What can I do?

```
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierBinding
```